# Paypal Express Checkout Negative test

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, express-checkout

I'm implementing the paypal Express Checkout Server-side REST with the php-sdk.
When I make a purchase with the buyer's account(with a positive balance) I can finalice the payments.

To validate that the payment is successful I use this code.

```
$result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
if ($result->state === "approved") {
    //Finalize the payment...
```

But I can not do negative tests. When I create a buyer account with a balance of $ 0.0 and I try to make a payment. Always returns the approved "state"

Es esta la forma correcta de validar los pagos? "state === 'approved'" or I need to use other atribute of the response?

¿How I can make negative test in Sandbox enviroment?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a sandbox account to simulate the customer/issue you want, just click on accounts in the sandbox section on the left hand menu.

So you could set up an account with no money or partial money or whatever  you need to test for and use those individual accounts to test.

Comment: Good tip. After fighting paypal integrations, I can say a sandbox account with multiple regional shopper accounts is a VERY good idea to diagnose with these edge cases.

Comment: @Randall it took me a moment to realise that, I had done 2 integrations before this obviousness hit me :) I am v. slow :)

Comment: @dops I am already using accounts created in the section that you comment. However, although the account does not have money, the payment always returns me in an approved state.

When the purchase is finalized correctly should the state be approved? Maybe just doing the wrong validation

Comment: @user3285408 in which case maybe this will help more https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/nt-rest/